# couldn't connect laravel with Postgresql

Tags: laravel, postgresql

I'm trying to **connect laravel project with postgreSQL** in localhost.
I already installed postgreSQL and pgAdmin 4 on windows and create a database
then trying to connect with my laravel project after I defined a new connection in `config/database.php`

with these configuration

```
'pgsql' => [
    'driver' => 'pgsql',
    'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
    'host' => 'localhost', 
    'port' => '5432', 
    'database' => 'MyDatabaseName', 
    'username' => 'postgres', 
    'password' => 'MyUserPassword', 
    'charset' => 'utf8',
    'prefix' => '',
    'prefix_indexes' => true,
    'search_path' => 'public',
    'sslmode' => 'prefer',
],
```

but it returns this error when running the project

```
SQLSTATE[08006] [7] could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061) Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432? FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgres"
```

Even though I entered the correct password !

Connect Laravel with PostgreSQL

Answer (score 1):

You have to change .env file like this

```
DB_CONNECTION=pgsql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=5432
DB_DATABASE=your_db_name
DB_USERNAME=postgres
DB_PASSWORD=your_db_passs
```

Comment: I did it though, but no need to this because i put the database configuration in  ```config/database.php```